# Copy embedded resource to Desktop C#

Tags: c#, resources, copy

I try to copy an embedded text file to desktop. My following code doesn't work. It throws three errors.

> An implicit conversion from string to byte[] is not possible]

The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string, byte[])' has some invalid arguments

> Argument '2': Conversion from string into byte[] isn't possible

```
string file1 = Properties.Resources.IMG_Resource_Filenames_txt.ToString();
File.WriteAllBytes(file1, NOS_File_Backup.Properties.Resources.IMG_Resource_Filenames_txt);
```

Does someone know how to fix? I already tried to convert my resource to byte with Convert.ToByte() ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NOS_File_Backup.Properties.Resources.IMG_Resource_Filenames_txt` is of string type but the `File.WriteAllBytes(...)` wants a byte array. This is why you get the error.

Try using `File.WriteAllText(...)` instead.